# What is Hull Weakness?

Tags: endless-space, endless-space-disharmony

Several of the new ship modules in Disharmony give "Hull Weakness X%".

What is Hull Weakness? Should I be worried?

Comment: In particular Shields add this, which is boggling my mind.

Comment: @C.Ross All the defenses have a penalty associated with them now. I think I may have jumped on the Disharmony wagon too soon...

Comment: But fighters and bombers!

Comment: Haven't tested (which is hard), but I think this increases the crit chance of attacks against the ship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Explanation from dev blog post:](http://forums.amplitude-studios.com/showthread.php?19080-Beta-patch-1.1.15-Balance-Update)

> Defence Type & Hulls
>    Since the release of Disharmony, the different
>   hulls have a new property called **Hull Weakness, which modulate the
>   received damage: the lowest hull weakness is, the more resistant the
>   hull.** A large ship has 100 Hull Weakness, a medium 200 and a small
>   300. The damage modulation is directly related to the value of the defence: the higher the defence value, the more efficient is a low
>   hull weakness. With this new patch, Deflector has the highest defence
>   value, then shield and finally flak. So that means that a large ship
>   receives a better protection from deflector than flak because of the
>   final impact of hull weakness will be lower in the first case.

Comment: Well that's... counter-intuitive.

Comment: @RavenDreamer yep but it is straight from the dev's mouth. I can see where they are coming from, you want a "low" weakness because weakness is bad.

Comment: Yeah, just wish they indicated that you didn't start at 0 weakness.